# How to put images in action sheet button?

Tags: iphone

I have created an action sheet which contains more than one button, and I want to put different images on different buttons, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can't, the "buttons" (actually a special class called a three part button, IIRC) in UIActionSheet are not directly accessible and you can't subclass it either. However it is pretty easy to write your own, see http://blog.corywiles.com/custom-uiactionsheet-using-core-animation for an example or inspiration. It's only a view with some buttons as subviews, and a bit of code to handle sliding it up from the bottom of the screen.